# почему изображение не растягивается на весь div?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите почему не растягивается img на весь div хотя я задал top:0;lefy:0;right:0 bottom:0;

P.S: хотелось бы услышать совет как сделать слайдер адаптивным

```css
#slider{
 max-width: 100%;
}
#slider .images{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
}
#slider .images .slide{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#slider .images .show{
 opacity: 1;
}

#slider ul{
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 bottom: 20px;
 left: 40%;
}
#slider ul li{
 list-style: none;
}
#slider .dot{
 display: block;
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 margin:0 10px;
 background: #D6D6D6;
 border-radius:100%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#slider .next{
 position: absolute;
 right:15px;
 top:55%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#slider .prev{
 position: absolute;
 left:15px;
 top:55%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="images">
    <img class="slide show" src="img/slider-img1.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="slide" src="img/slider-img2.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="slide" src="img/slider-img3.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="slide" src="img/slider-img4.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="slide" src="img/slider-img5.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="dot"></span></li>
        <li><span class="dot"></span></li>
        <li><span class="dot"></span></li>
        <li><span class="dot"></span></li>
        <li><span class="dot"></span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="contr-slider" >
      <img src="img/left.svg" alt="" class="prev">
      <img src="img/right.svg" alt="" class="next">
    </div>
</div>
```

вся верстка [здесь](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h12OcQasrVbik582g99qEWqMt0p_5-y4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробовал вместо

```
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
```

прописал

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

картинки растягиваются на весь слайд. Вам это нужно было?

Answer (score 0):

`top,left,right и bottom` задают положение, а не размер.
Для растягивания примените `width и height`